# decorating a function that yields

Tags: python, generator, decorator, yield, python-decorators

Is it possible, and if so, advisable, and if so, what would be the recommended method for decorating a function that yields a value?

For example, consider this imaginary example I made up

```
def foobar_creator(func):
    def wrapped(**kwargs):
       res = func(**kwargs)
       flag = True
       for k,v in kwargs:
           if res % v == 0:
               flag = False
               yield k
       if flag: 
            yield res
     return wrapped

@foobar_creator
def generic_yielder(**kwargs):
     for i in xrange(sys.maxint):
           yield i

for i in generic_yielder(foo=3, bar=5, foobar=15):
      print i
```

Comment: Looks overcomplicated. What specifically do you mean by "decorating a function that yields a value"? What use case do you have in mind?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev use case: i have a bunch of generator functions that yield new values from an api. I want to apply filters without touching the existing function. So for a stripped down exmaple example `def get_new(): result = new_result(); yield result`  I want to filter out and yield only, say results which contain the string 'foobar' without mucking the complicated `new_result` processes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A generator function, when called, returns an iterator object. If your decorator is itself a generator too, you'll need to *loop* over the wrapped result:

```
def foobar_creator(func):
    def wrapped(**kwargs):
        gen = func(**kwargs)
        flag = True
        for k, v in kwargs:
            if res % v == 0:
                flag = False
                yield k
        if flag:
            for res in gen:
                yield res
    return wrapped
```

If you are using Python 3.3 or up, you can use *delegation* to hand control the wrapped generator, by using `yield from`:

```
if flag:
    yield from gen
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of yielding every *potential* return value, why not yield only those that *actually exist?* Something like

```
def wrap(f, arg):
    for x in f(arg):
        yield x
```

(actual decorator syntax, handling of positional and keyword arguments, etc. is omitted for clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

For the case in [comment42684128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087825/decorating-a-function-that-yields?noredirect=1#comment42684128_27087825), the solution is as simple as:

```
(v for v in f(<args>) if filter_condition(v))
```

As a decorator:

```
def yfilter(filter_condition):
   def yfilter_p(f):
       def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
           return (v for v in f(*args,**kwargs) if filter_condition(v))
       return wrapped
   return yfilter_p
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers don't handle generators that yield and then return a value. For that, you need to `return (yield from f())`:

```py
def dec(f):
    def g():
        return (yield from f())
    return g

@dec
def f():
   yield 'val'
   return 'done'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to decorate using type hints, do it like this

```
from typing import Generator

def generate() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531262/1812732

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. I guess you don't know what decorators are?

Comment: but maybe someone will find this useful.   i would have.