# How to type hint a generator in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

According to [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-generator-functions-and-coroutines), we should be able to type hinting a generator function as follows:

```py
from typing import Generator

def generate() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

for i in generate():
    print(i)
```

However, the list comprehension gives the following error in PyCharm.

> Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'Generator[int, None, None]' instead less... (⌘F1)

Any idea why PyCharm is considering this as error?

---

A few clarification after reading some answers. I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2 (the latest version) and have imported the `typing.Generator` (updated in the code). The above code runs just fine, but PyCharm considers this an error:

[image]

So, I'm wondering if this is actually an error or an unsupported feature in PyCharm.

Comment: What happens when you change your code to this: http://ideone.com/IwHbT0 ?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22071

Comment: I use Pycharm 2017.1 EAP and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: The EAP indeed solved this issue; thank you very much.

Comment: I am confused... the OP's code works, **and** it is exactly the same code as the #1 answer has, where the author opens with "You need to import the `typing` module", even though the OP *did in fact include the `typing` module*.  Was there a massive edit that made this question moot?  Not as far as I can tell, though...

Comment: @MikeWilliamson yes, it was an edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42531143/2. It looks like the real question is PyCharm, not Python. The top answer has been updated to mention that, too. I dunno what should be done with this confusing Q/A per SO standards.

Comment: Is this even about PyCharm or is there some other tool that PyCharm uses under the hood?

Answer (score 180):

You need to import the `typing` module. As per docs:

> The return type of generator functions can be annotated by the generic
>   type `Generator[yield_type, send_type, return_type]` provided by
>   **`typing.py` module**

Try this way instead:

```
from typing import Generator


def generate() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

The above will have the desired result:

```
l = [i for i in generate()]
```

Output:

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

---

As pointed out in the comments, you might not use the last version of PyCharm. Try switching to version *2016.3.2* and you *might* be fine. Unfortunately this is a well-known bug, as per @AshwiniChaudhary comment.

More, the reported issue (for the last version of PyCharm) was submitted on December, last year. They probably fixed it and pushed the modifications into the same version.

Comment: Shouldn't that result in `NameError` for `Generator ` for OP?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary why would it ? I just tested it and it works exactly as is.

Comment: Issue is not with output, issue is with PyCharm complaining about return type. Have you tested it in PyCharm?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is correct, the OP has already made the import (even though it's not shown in their code snippet) otherwise they'd get a `NameError`

Comment: The OP probably needs to update his Pycharm to _2016.3.2_. I've got a warning even with the latest version, but not an error :)

Comment: As per the comment here(https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17890) it is present in 2016.3.2 as well.

Comment: what's a `send_type`?

Comment: @minseong it's a type of value used in `generator.send()` function. With Python generators, you can both receive values which are yielded and send values to generators, which will replace the current yield expression. See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose

Comment: Is there more modern syntax yet?

Answer (score 138):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but I think it is a better solution.

I'm using the typing specification below, using `Iterator[int]` instead of Generator. The validation is OK. I think it is a lot clearer. It better describes the code intention and is recommended by [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Generator).

```
from typing import Iterator

def generate() -> Iterator[int]:
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

It would also allow future refactorings if you change your Generator for a list or other iterable.

I'm using Visual Studio Code with PyLance for typing validation. PyCharm mypy should have the same behavior.

If you are using *Python 3.10 or superior*, change the import command above to:

```
from collections.abc import Iterator
```

Comment: I am not sure why this got downvoted. The python doc itself states, that is it possible to use `Iterator[YieldType]` or `Iterable[YieldType]` for generators, which yield only. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

Comment: `from collections.abc import Iterator` is the new preferable way. See https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable

Comment: Yeah, much clearer provided you don't use send / return here.

Comment: The caveat to this is that you can get type errors if you use any of the magic methods created for Generators, i.e. `send`, `throw` or `close`.

Answer (score 11):

The `Iterator`, `Generator`, and `Iterable` are slightly different in details and carry different type of information, so understanding the difference might help choosing the correct one for your code:

- `Iterable` is the most general term among these three, representing any object that can be iterated over. An `Iterable` must have an `__iter__()` method that returns an iterator, or a `__getitem__()` method with sequential indices starting from `0`.
- `Iterator` is a subtype of `Iterable`. An `Iterator` is an object that implements the iterator protocol, which includes the `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods. The `__iter__()` method should return the iterator object itself, and the `__next__()` method should return the next value from the iterator.
- `Generator` is a more specialized subtype of `Iterator`. A `Generator` object is produced by calling a generator function, which is defined using the `yield` keyword. The `Generator` type is unique as it has two additional type parameters for its send and return types, allowing more expressive type hinting especially when the generator is used for co-routine-like patterns. Unlike `Iterator` and `Iterable`, the `Generator` type can be used to specify the types of values that can be sent to or returned from the generator, using the syntax `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]`.

So, how to type hint mainly depends on what your code is really doing:

- Use `Iterable` when a function is expected to accept any iterable object without concerning the exact type of the iterator.
- Use `Iterator` when the function is expected to work specifically with iterator objects, without specifying the exact subtype of the iterator.
- Use `Generator` to explicitly indicate that a function returns/accepts a generator object, and optionally specify the types of values that can be sent to or returned from the generator.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this really clearly lays out the options. One follow question: you mentioned that "Generator functions return iterators", but also say that "I'd use Generator to explicitly convey that a function returns a generator". Why wouldn't you just use the Iterator signature as you initially said? I suspect that the answer has something to do with bi-directional generators (i.e. yield from) but would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: There are possible use cases where your code should always use generators, for i.e. resource management reasons or so. And the only way to tell the linter so is to use `Generator` hinting, because remaining two, despite being wider in scope, do not provide any information about where they come from.

Comment: There are a few things incorrect/imprecise about your generator definition: Yes, the `Generator` type is more specific because it is literally a subtype of `Iterator` (which is a subtype of `Iterable`). But `yield` is not exclusive to generators. A function defined with the `yield` statement (called a generator function) _returns_ a generator and due to the subtype relation that returned object is always _also_ an iterator (and an iterable). The main distinction is that `Generator` (unlike its supertype) has two additional type parameters, namely for its **send** and **return** types.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to cover that, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For simple iterators/generators this seems solved but even in the [PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#annotating-generator-functions-and-coroutines) I don't see how to do this with multiple outputs. This is what I have now:

If needing to yield 2 variables one can do:

```
import typing

def iter_things() -> typing.Iteraror[tuple[int, str]]:
    for i in range(42):
        yield i, '#' * i
```

For more outputs amend to the `tuple`.

Using `typing.Generator` you'd need a little more convoluted `typing.Generator[tuple[int, str], None, None]`

Yielding dedicated typed things from a dictionary the setup is:

```
import typing

def iter_things() -> typing.ItemsView[str, int]:
    return BLOOORBS.items()
```

Comment: Because the `ItemsView` is a concrete iterator of pairs, the concrete type takes care of packing the items. When using a more generic type like `Generator` or `Iterator`, you need to spell out this property explicitely, hence the tuple. That's like complaining that you have to specify the key and value for a dict but with a custom non-generic mapping you don't.

Comment: If you want to simplify your code though, you can type the generator as an `Iterator` and drop the last two parameters, it works fine. It just limits the use to an iterator rather than a coroutine proper.

Comment: Hey @Masklinn thank you! I changed the text and removed the flavoring suggesting I was "complaining" :) didn't really intent to. I guess `Iterator` would suffice for most of the cases 