# Proper typing for a interesting 'yield' function

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, type-annotation

Python typing documentation includes examples for typing of generator functions. Yield is still a concept I struggle to understand, but I have a scenario where I'm not quite sure, how to properly use typing. The code is a very basic example of my current struggle and shows where my question arises from. If I have two yields in a function, how would I use typing for that function? The documentation on [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) gives me no clear answer, my current preference would be, to use Iterator[dict].

```
def yield_func() -> ?:
    A: dict = {}
    B: dict = {}

    yield A
    yield B
```

I would currently use Iterator[dict] as typing annotations for the given function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint a generator in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531143/how-to-type-hint-a-generator-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most flexible form is the one [explained here already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531262/19770795) and alluded to again by @tomerar. It was already mentioned in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#annotating-generator-functions-and-coroutines) way back in the day. The generic alias [`Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Generator) from `collections.abc` is what you can use.

Since your example generator is very simple in that it does *not* have a return value and does *not* utilize sending anything to it, you can use the more basic [`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) type, which is a supertype of `Generator` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)). An `Iterator` is generic only in terms of the type its `__next__`  method returns, which is equivalent to the type you **yield** in a generator function.

I would suggest always using those generic alias types from `collections.abc` and **not** from `typing` (unless you are on Python `<3.9`) because the typing equivalents are **deprecated** (see [for example here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator)).

By the way, if you are already taking the time to annotate your functions (which is great), you should properly utilize generic types, which include `dict`. Here is how I would annotate your example function assuming the keys in your dictionaries are `str` and without knowing anything about the value-type:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

MyDictT = dict[str, object]  # for example

def yield_func() -> Iterator[MyDictT]:
    a: MyDictT = {}
    b: MyDictT = {}
    ...
    yield a
    yield b
```